# FacebookSDK iOS v3.24.0-beta1

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-ios-sdk, ios9

I'm testing **FacebookSDK ios v3.24.0-beta1** from Facebook Developer site.
My test environment is iOS9 beta5 on iphone6+ and test app is built on Xcode7 beta-6.

I have set the info.plist for iOS9 App transport security.
And I have installed Facebook App in my device.

I try to login facebook using

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions:defaultAudience:allowLoginUI:completionHandler:]
```

When I invoke the method. The facebook app is not launched. But I can see the login dialog in webview (I guess).

Question: I want to know whether after the **v3.24.0-beta** is not support app to app login.

Comment: I assume you have followed this guide? https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9

Comment: Yes. I saw the notice. I just want to know about roadmap and policy. Because I have to provide for my customer using my middleware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design. In order to provide the best experience for users on iOS 9, the new SDK determines the best login flow automatically. If you're running on iOS 8 or earlier, the app switch will still be preferred.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I saw facebook sdk source codes on github. so I understand your login flow.